# Revise the Google Script, It is not working after update

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the script below as a Time Stamp and save the changes, so i can check how much changes has been done. The problem is now the script is not working after update v8?
Can anyone help with this, what is the issue with my script?

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = s.getName();
  var rowIndex = e.range.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = e.range.getColumnIndex();
  var actionCol1 = 14;
  var tSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("History bg pending");


  if(sheet=="Hard Live tracker"){
  if(e.value != null && colIndex == actionCol1){  
    e.range.offset(0,9).setValue(new Date ()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    var tRange = tSheet.getRange(tSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colIndex+9);
    var sRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colIndex+10);
    sRange.copyTo(tRange);
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Are you using a [Time-driven installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)? Could you share the whole function please?

Comment: No using Time-Driven sir, it is only time stamping the data when someone update the specific column as the trigger.

That is the whole function

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce your error (even with an old script that I had with the deprecated version and then I passed it to V8) and it's working for me. Are you using the [Installale Trigger onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)?